# Trying to start a container in docker desktop and it returns Error(HTTP code 502) unexpected

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, docker-desktop

I am fairly new to using containers and this is my first time facing this issue. It used to start up just fine until yesterday but today it stopped working for some reason. The only thing that I could have changed yesterday was that I installed some packages to my visual studio for which were Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore and Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.SQLServer.
Otherwise in logs it is returning "Error response from daemon: failed to get logging factory: logger: no log driver named '' is registered: error looking up logging plugin : legacy plugin: Unable to find plugin without name".
I would appreciate any advice on how to fix it.

To start a docker container.